# Using Java nio to create a subdirectory and file

Tags: java, file, nio

I'm creating a simple program that will try to read in "conf/conf.xml" from disk, but if this file or dir doesn't exist will instead create them.

I can do this using the following code:

```
    // create subdirectory path
    Path confDir = Paths.get("./conf"); 

    // create file-in-subdirectory path
    Path confFile = Paths.get("./conf/conf.xml"); 

    // if the sub-directory doesn't exist then create it
    if (Files.notExists(confDir)) { 
        try { Files.createDirectory(confDir); }
        catch (Exception e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }

    // if the file doesn't exist then create it
    if (Files.notExists(confFile)) {
        try { Files.createFile(confFile); }
        catch (Exception e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
```

My questions is if this really the most elegant way to do this? It seems superflous to need to create two Paths simple to create a new file in a new subdirectory.

Comment: `Path` has `.resolve()` and `.getParent()`, so you could start there

Comment: I don't get your exception logic: Why do you try to create the file if the directory does not exist and can't be created?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could declare your `confFile` as `File` instead of `Path`. Then you can use `confFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();`, see example below:

```
// ...

File confFile = new File("./conf/conf.xml"); 
confFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();

// ...
```

Or, using your code as is, you can use:

```
Files.createDirectories(confFile.getParent());
```

Comment: Wouldn't using mkdirs() or createDirectories(..) trip an exception if .conf/ already existed?I can see how it could be done with File, but wondered why the Paths/Files under nio didn't have an equally simply way to do this.

Comment: @user3341332 No. It doesn't throw exceptions at all. See the Javadoc.

Comment: But note that `Path.getParent()` return `null` if there is no more parts in the "string" of the Path. For example a `Path` with `dir/b.txt` will return path `dir` but `dir.getParent()` will return `null`. So `Files.createDirectories(dir.getParent());` throw a `NullPointerException` although `dir`is inside other directory.

Comment: why go back to java.io.File when you're starting with java.nio.Path?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27069447/nio-getparentfile-mkdir#answer-27069848

Comment: File confFile = new File("./conf/conf.xml");  is java.io, not java.nio ...

Answer (score 4):

You can create directory and file in one code line:

`Files.createFile(Files.createDirectories(confDir).resolve(confFile.getFileName()))`

`Files.createDirectories(confDir)` will not throw an exception if the folder already exists and returns Path in any case.

Comment: `Files.createDirectories(confDir)` will throw a `FileAlreadyExistsException`, if the directory already exists.

Comment: @mks-d I verified - run the code 2 times and don't get the exception. Which java version you use?

Comment: @ValeriyK. good point. And my bad since it was with `createDirectory​(Path)` and not `createDirectories(Path)`. The version was ancient, Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
// Get your Path from the string
Path confFile = Paths.get("./conf/conf.xml"); 
// Get the portion of path that represtents directory structure.  
Path subpath = confFile.subpath(0, confFile.getNameCount() - 1);
// Create all directories recursively
/**
     * Creates a directory by creating all nonexistent parent directories first.
     * Unlike the {@link #createDirectory createDirectory} method, an exception
     * is not thrown if the directory could not be created because it already
     * exists.
     *
*/
Files.createDirectories(subpath.toAbsolutePath()))
```